# set padding to dynamic textbox C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, alignment

here is the code I create textbox from C# code..

```
for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
            {
                            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                            txt.ID = "txt - " + x.ToString(); 
                            data.Controls.Add(txt);
                            data.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
             }
```

all textbox will be stick to each other.. I wonder can I add padding-top in the loop? how may I do it?

thanks for your help and your suggestion and comment is appreaciated.

This is create by using C#
[image]

I wish want got space like this. 
[image]

please ignore the drop down box.. its just example.

Comment: Just use CSS to add styles like padding to your controls in your stylesheet

Comment: See my answer with some information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know something about `CSS` and `stylesheets`?
You can render anything you want in the backend like in your example: textboxes.
Using CSS you can add some style to it. This doesn't needs to be done during the creation of your controls.

In your example just create a stylesheet like `default.css` and add it into your page using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/default.css" />
```

Then using following code you can add some padding or even better some margin to your inputs:

```
input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Another solution is using classes:

**ASP.NET**

```
for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
{
     TextBox txt = new TextBox();
     txt.ID = "txt - " + x.ToString(); 
     txt.CssClass = "form-control"; //Assign a css class to your textbox
     data.Controls.Add(txt);
     data.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
}
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```