# Bootstrap Style & Surrounding Div tag from ASP.NET Code Behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing an ASP.NET application where I have to create "TextBox" & "DropdownList" controls dynamically. 
Following is the method I use to create "TextBox" controls.

```
private void CreateTextBox(string id, string labelName)
{
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl.Text = labelName;
     pnlDynamicControls.Controls.Add(lbl);

     TextBox txt = new TextBox();
     txt.ID = id;
     pnlDynamicControls.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

I'm using the bootstrap theme to create my pages. Following is a styled "Textbox".

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Document Base:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox >
</div>
```

I want this style to be applied to the dynamically creating "TextBox" controls & the "div" tag surrounding it.
How can I achieve this?

I'm using ASP.NET with C#, Bootstrap 3, VS2017

**Update:**
Following image shows, how it looks when I add the CssClass to the control
[image: When Added the style]

I want it to look as follows
[image: What i want]

Comment: [above-mentioned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885074/set-padding-to-dynamic-textbox-c-sharp-asp-net) only add the style to control. I want the surrounding "Div" tag also to be added to markup dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CssClass property.

```
private void CreateTextBox(string id, string labelName)
{
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl.cssClass = "col-sm-2 control-label";
     lbl.Text = labelName;
     pnlDynamicControls.Controls.Add(lbl);

     TextBox txt = new TextBox();
     txt.cssClass = "form-control";
     txt.ID = id;
     pnlDynamicControls.Controls.Add(txt); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this. but this will only add the style to controls. I want the "<div class="form-group">" to be added to the markup